# Shelah's uncountable categoricity theorem

Tags: logic, model-theory

Morley's theorem says if $T$ is a complete theory in a countable language and $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for some uncountable $\kappa$, then $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for any uncountable $\kappa$. Shelah generalized this theorem to uncountable languages, but I can't find the exact statement.

In particular, if $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for some $\kappa$ greater (or also equal?) than $|T|$, then $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical for every $\kappa$ greater (or also equal) than $|T|$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Not clear what your question is. Can you update it?

Comment: I can't find the exact statement of the Shelah's generalization of the Morley categoricity theorem. In particular, If T is k'-categorical for some k' greater (or also equal?) than k, t is k'-categorical  for every k' greater (or also equal) than k?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, k is the cardinality of the language of T

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wikipedia page for [Categorical theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_theory) answers your question (emphasis mine):

> Saharon Shelah extended Morley's theorem to uncountable languages: if the language has cardinality $\kappa$ and a theory is categorical in some uncountable cardinal **greater than or equal to** $\kappa$ then it is categorical in all cardinalities **greater than** $\kappa$.

Now this is actually a bit stronger than you might expect! Morley's theorem says that if a theory in a countable language is categorical in a cardinal **greater than** $\aleph_0$, then it is categorical in all cardinalities **greater than** $\aleph_0$. On the other hand, if a theory in a countable language is categorical in a cardinal **equal to** $\aleph_0$ (i.e. the theory is countably categorical), this does not guarantee categoricity in any other cardinals.

Shelah's possibly surprising result, as stated above, puts together two theorems from Chapter IX of *Classification Theory* (pages 490 and 491). Theorem 1.16 is the natural generalization of Morley's theorem, and Theorem 1.19 deals separately with the case of a theory $T$ which is $|T|$-categorical, showing that this case trivializes when $|T|$ is uncountable.

> THEOREM 1.16: Suppose $T$ is categorical in some $\lambda > |T|$ or every model of $T$ of cardinality $\lambda$ (for some $\lambda>|T|$) is $|T|^+$-universal. Then $T$ is categorical in every $\mu > |T|$, and every model of $T$ of cardinality $>|T|$ is saturated.

> THEOREM 1.19: If $T$ is categorical in $|T|>\aleph_0$, then $T$ is a definitional extension of some $T'\subseteq T$, $|T'|<|T|$.

The point is that if $T$ is a definitional expansion of $T'$, then there is a one-to-one cardinality-preserving correspondence between the models of $T$ and the models of $T'$. If $T$ is $|T|$-categorical, then $T'$ is also $|T|$-categorical. Since $|T'|<|T|$, by Theorem 1.16, $T'$ is $\kappa$-categorical for all $\kappa > |T'|$. So also $T$ is  $\kappa$-categorical for all $\kappa>|T'|$, and in particular for all $\kappa>|T|$.

What's happened here is that the uncountable $|T|$-categorical theory $T$ is "secretly" just a theory of smaller cardinality. And this is really quite a silly situation to be in! To say that $T$ is a definitional expansion of $T'$ is to say that every symbol in the language of $T$ which is not in the language of $T'$ is defined by a formula in the language of $T'$. But there are only $|T'|$-many formulas in the language of $T'$, so while there are $|T|$-many new symbols, up to equivalence there are only $|T'|$-many!

To give an explicit example, we could take $T'$ to be the theory of algebraically closed fields and take $T$ to be the theory obtained by introducing uncountably many constant symbols $\{c_\alpha\mid \alpha\in \kappa\}$ and setting them all to $0$ by adding axioms $c_\alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha$. Theorem 1.19 says that every example has to be almost as trivial as this one. Upshot: the behavior of countable $\aleph_0$-categorical theories is very special to the countable.